# no pods can be started: failed calling webhook "gvisor.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Our GKE cluster can't start any pods with following error:

> failed calling webhook "gvisor.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io": Post https://localhost:5443/webhook/gvisor?timeout=30s: dial tcp [::1]:5443: connect: connection refused

luckily we were able to recover by upgrading master version, which triggered restart of a control plane, but what if we were already on a latest master version? As far as I am aware there is no way to cycle master nodes via API.

Answer (score 0):

The error message basically just mean that the common webhook went down for a short period of time.

However, version **1.14.3-gke.12** or above should fix this issue in regards to webhook.

But you have said that you already upgraded your master version, so you should be okay! If you haven't upgraded to **1.14.3-gke.12** or above yet, please do so.

If you need to know how to manually upgrading a cluster or node pool, just click on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Anthony, my question is more about what to do if we hit the bug like that, but there is no new version released yet.

Comment: Hello again, it seems that this error should not happen again after version 1.14.3-gke.12 is released. However, I cannot provide a date on when that version will be released.

Comment: If you do hit a bug similar again in the future, it would be advised to create a support case with GCP so that way, they can fully analyze your project and give you better results. Here is the link: https://cloud.google.com/contact/

Comment: Just as additional information, if you will ever encounter similar situation, you can reach `Google Support` using [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and get additional information, if this is a Bug or issue with your cluster configuration.